# Person Is Valid SharePoint User [MultiUser]

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, validation

I have a list with column named 'MultiUser'
[DataType: Person or Group, **Multiple Selection Yes**]

I want to validate all the Users in List using SharePoint Designer. I can do this if there is only one value in the column 'MultiUser' by using Condition "**Person Is Valid SharePoint User**"

To Validate Multiple SharePoint User via SharePoint Designer i followed the following  steps
[image: Condition to Validate MultiUser]

The above statement/condition always falls in **Else Part** even the users are valid.

[image: WorkFlow to Validate Multiple User]